# How to remove rows from a dataframe

Tags: r

I created a random set of 73 values in R.

```
randomvalues <- sample(x=1:365, size = 73)
```

Now I'd like to purposely create missing values by removing the max temperature from the rows that correspond with those random values. Eg if '3' was one of the random numbers generated, then the value 26.8 should be removed.

[image]

This is what I've tried so far:

```
rawdata2 <- rawdata1[-randomvalues]
```

The error message I received was:

```
Error: Subscript `-randomvalues` is a matrix, it must be of type logical.
```

What should I do instead? Am new to R so appreciate any help from you all.

Thank you.

*Sorry, wasn't clear with my initial explanation.

Comment: If it is a data.frame/matrix, use `rawdata1[-randomvalues,]` i.e. `,` to separte the row/column index.  In data.frame, by defaault, if you don't specify the `,`, it would be column index

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  I have revised the question as I realised my initial description wasn't clear.

Comment: data frames/tibbles work with [rows, colums] index. so you can set the values of certain row indices for a specific column like: `df[rowindices, "max_temp"] <- NA`

Comment: Thanks so much @Ray.